# Laravel: Eager loading with local scope

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a Coupon model in a Many to Many relation with a Product model (with pivot table and so on...). I created some local scope to get only available coupons, and to get only coupons of determined category:

```
public function scopeAvailable($query)
{    
    return $query->where('available', '>', 0);
}

public function scopeOfCategory($query, $category)
{
  return $query->join('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'coupons.category_id')
    ->where('categories.slug', $category);
}
```

I want to eager load all available coupons of some category with their respective products. So I'm doing:

```
$coupons = Coupon::with('products')->available()->ofCategory($category)->paginate(20);
```

If I call `$coupons->first()`, I can see the information about the coupon. But if I call `$coupons->first()->products` I get an empty array.

If I comment the `->ofCategory($category)` part, it works as expected.

Here is my Models:

```
class Coupon extends Model
{

  public function products()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product');
  }
  ...
}

class Product extends Model
{
  public function coupons()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Coupon');
  }
  ...
}
```

I'm using Laravel 5.2. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:** 
It looks like a problem with my Category. If I try to get coupons on "other" category, I got my coupon as expected. If I try to get coupons on "electronics" category, I got a coupon with no products. I'm pretty sure I have coupons with products both on "electronics" and "other" categories.

If I dump `Category::where('slug', '=', 'electronics')->first()`:

```
...
protected 'attributes' => 
  array (size=3)
    'id' => int 1
    'name' => string 'Electronics' (length=11)
    'slug' => string 'electronics' (length=11)
...
```

If I dump `Category::where('slug', '=', 'other')->first()`:
    ...
    protected 'attributes' => 
      array (size=3)
        'id' => int 2
        'name' => string 'Other' (length=5)
        'slug' => string 'other' (length=5)
    ...

**Edit 2:**
I created another coupons with "other" category, so I have two coupons with this category. When I print the coupons, it shows the first coupon twice.

Comment: Are you sure that when you do `$coupons->first()` the first record's  category is the same category as `$category`?

Comment: That is very strange. If I choose the "other" category, it works as expected. If I choose "electronics" category, I got that empty array.

Comment: Are you sure that you have records for all categories? Can you post your category model too? :)

Comment: If I print the SQL query, I can see that I have 1 "electronics" coupon with 1 product, and 1 "other"  coupon with 1 product.

My Category model just have a $guard array with name and slug values.

Comment: I registered another coupon with another product on "other" category. If I try to get all products with this category, it fails. I changed the new product category to "electronics" and it works. I don't know whats is happening.

Answer (score 2):

Table `coupons`:

```
| id |    name    | available | category_id |
|----|------------|-----------|-------------|
| 1  | Coupon #1  |     1     |     1       |
| 2  | Coupon #2  |     1     |     1       |
| 3  | Coupon #3  |     1     |     1       |
```

Table `products`:

```
| id |    name     |
|----|-------------|
| 1  | Product #1  |
| 2  | Product #2  |
| 3  | Product #3  |
```

Table `coupon_product`:

```
| id |product_id| coupon_id |
|----|----------|-----------|
| 1  |     1    |     1     |
| 2  |     2    |     1     |
```

Table `categories`:

```
| id |    slug     |
|----|-------------|
| 1  | category-1  |
| 2  | category-2  |
| 3  | category-3  |
```

`Product.php`:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    public function coupons()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Coupon');
    }
}
```

`Coupon.php`:

```
class Coupon extends Model
{
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product');
    }

    public function scopeAvailable($query)
    {
        return $query->where('available', '>', 0);
    }

    public function scopeOfCategory($query, $category)
    {
        return $query->join('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'coupons.category_id')
            ->where('categories.slug', $category);
    }
}
```

And finally when I run:

```
$coupons = App\Coupon::with('products')->available()->ofCategory('funny')->first();
dd($coupons->products);
```

I get this:

[image]

Which is correct. Can you post more detailed info about your current state of the project?

Comment: That is exactly what I have in my code. But when I output the results. I got Collection { #items: [] } on "other" category, and Collection { #items: array:1 } on "electronics" category

Comment: Can you dump this `App\Category::where('slug', '=', 'electronics')->first()` and post the result as an edit to your question?

Comment: I created other coupons with other categories. Only coupons with category id 1 are been returned.